# How can I change Cypress browser language?

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to run tests with Cypress using **electron** **browser**, but the system language is changed according to the language of the browser. This is making the tests fail.

I've tried to override `visit` method as in the code below, but didn't work.

```
/ commands.js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite("visit", (originalVisit, url, options = {}) => {
  console.log('calling cy.visit')
  const opts = {
    onBeforeLoad: (win) => {
      Object.defineProperty(win.navigator, 'language', {
        value: 'pt-BR'
      })
    },
    onLoad: (win) => {
      console.log('onLoad')
    }
  }
  return originalVisit(url, opts)
})
```

My question is: Is there any way I can configure the browser to always start with a specific language?

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your browser launch preferences. For your specific case, this piece of code could be useful:

```
on('before:browser:launch', (browser, launchOptions) => {
   if (browser.family === 'chromium') {
     launchOptions.preferences.default.intl = { accept_languages: 'pt-BR' };
     return launchOptions;
   }
});
```

https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/browser-launch-api.html#Modify-browser-launch-arguments-preferences-and-extensions

Comment: I tried, but there is an error when trying to find the intl property. Any other suggestions?

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using the Electron browser.