# Is there a way to change the browser locale in Cypress?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress

I have looked around online and quite a bit on stackoverflow and cant seem to find an up-to-date answer for this question. I have found other questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56791796/how-to-set-the-browsers-language-in-cypress-io-electron-chrome), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54671266/setting-the-browser-language-in-cypress), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64284352/how-can-i-change-cypress-browser-language) - and none of those solution work anymore. Does anyone know if this functionality is available in Cypress or if there's a way to force a locale change? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's not too easy - as this differs from the browser you will be running your tests in.

Also, I believe that only are testing that your application looks and behaves right when the USER selected a specific language, you should consider adding a parameter when initiating your test session, e.g.

`http://myapp.com/start?lang=en`

then storing the selected language in LocaleStorage or a Cookie and selecting the language from there, as it is a lot more portable - and you will have users wanting to use your application in a different language than the browser default.

Still, There might be a few scenarios (e.g. if you want to tests, that your application detects the browser language correctly) where setting the browser language can be required, but I would suggest keeping tests that rely on a browser configuration to a minimum.

Is is possible tho, at least for Electron (verified with Electron 100) and Firefox (verified with Firefox 102). It used to work in Chrome too, but doesn't work for me anymore.

**For Electron:**

As Electron is being started along with the cypress GUI, changing the language afterwards is not possible. But you can expose an environment variable to the process, e.g.

```bash
ELECTRON_EXTRA_LAUNCH_ARGS=--lang=en npx cypress open
```

to start electron with the wanted locale.

**For Firefox:**

In your cypress.config.ts expand the defineConfig to contain such a block:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  // ...
  e2e: {
    // ....
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('before:browser:launch', (browser, launchOptions) => {

        if (browser.family === 'firefox') {
          launchOptions.preferences['intl.locale.requested'] = "en_US"
          return launchOptions
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The Firefox Setup will only work, if you have no other Firefox instance running in another locale.